# can read data from firebase with user_id from onAuthStateChanged

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

i just make simple input code, and it works with `userId`. But, i can read my data from child if i use `.child(userId)`. I try to convert into string before i put it on `child()`, but still won't work. It will work if i use my `userId` like this `.child('iOtzRxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')`. If i use `.child(userId)`, it give me error like this :   Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "undefined". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]".

How i can read my data from `.child(userId)` if i can input my data with `.child(userId)` ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Signin Template for Bootstrap</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.11.0/firebase.js"></script>
        <script src="core.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <input type="text" id="masukan">
            <button class="btn btn-primary small" id="input">Input Data</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger small" id="keluar">Signout</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success small" id="fresh_uid">Fres UID</button>
            <h1 id="userss"></h1>
            <h1 id="user_uid"></h1>
            <pre id="json"></pre>
            
        </div>
        <script>
            
            var txtinput = document.getElementById('masukan');

            var inputRed    = firebase.database().ref('users');
            
            var user_id; //User uid from onAuthStateChanged
            
            //Input value
            document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('click', e =>{
                inputRed.child(user_id).push({username: txtinput.value});
            });
            
            //Read data
            //inputRed.child('USER_UID_STRING').on('child_added', function(snapshot){
            
            inputRed.child(user_id).on('child_added', function(snapshot){
               document.getElementById('userss').innerText = snapshot.val().username;
            });
            
            //Read UID
            document.getElementById('fresh_uid').addEventListener('click', function(e){
                document.getElementById('user_uid').innerText = user_id;
            });
            
            //Sign Out
            document.getElementById('keluar').addEventListener('click', e =>{
                firebase.auth().signOut();
            });
            
            //Read current user
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser =>{
                if(firebaseUser){
                    var namaLengkap     = firebaseUser.displayName;
                    //document.getElementById('json').textContent = JSON.stringify(firebaseUser, null, ' ');
                    user_id = firebaseUser.uid;
                }
            });
        
        </script>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You set `user_id` at the end of your script, but you use it at the beginning. At that point, `user_id` is undefined.

Comment: how about write data ?it should be undefined, right ?

Comment: I have no idea what do you mean by *"write data"*. There isn't any data write in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is super-confusing and I didn't get it at all. But looking at your code - you set `user_id` in:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser =>{
    if(firebaseUser){
        var namaLengkap     = firebaseUser.displayName;
        //document.getElementById('json').textContent = JSON.stringify(firebaseUser, null, ' ');
        user_id = firebaseUser.uid;
    }
});
```

It is the last thing you do in your script. And it's conditional. But you use `user_id` many times before. So every time you use `user_id`, for example in:

```
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('click', e =>{
    inputRed.child(user_id).push({username: txtinput.value});
});
```

`user_id` evaluates to `undefined`. It has no value.

Comment: sorry for making you confusing. The actual problem is in `input` ( input data into Firebase ) and `user_id` as the output. If you said `user_id` is `undefined`, why i can insert data into Firebase with `user_id`, but can't read my data with `user_id` ?